# Insertion Sort method with Ruby weirdly skipped one swapping cycle, can't figure out why

Tags: ruby, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops, insertion-sort

As mentioned above, the code could run but skipped swapping numbers at round 6.

```
def insertion_sort(list)
  num = list.length
  for i in (0..(num-2))
    p i
    if list[i] > list[i+1] 
      len = (list[0..(i+1)].length)
      list2 = list[0..(i+1)]
      list = list - list2
      count = 0
      while count < len
        if list2[len-1] < list2[len-2]
           list2[len-2],list2[len-1]= list2[len-1],list2[len-2]  
        else
          count+=1
          len-=1
        end
      end
      list = list2 + list  
    end
    p list
  end
  list
end


insertion_sort([2,5,1,4,8,6,7,3,100,99])
```

As showing below, number 3 stopped at the wrong place at round 6.

0
[2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 6, 7, 3, 100, 99]

1
[1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6, 7, 3, 100, 99]

2
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7, 3, 100, 99]

3
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7, 3, 100, 99]

4
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 3, 100, 99]

5
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 100, 99]

6
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 100, 99]

7
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 100, 99]

8
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 99, 100]

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsxyg.png)

Could anyone help pointing out which part of the code is causing this?
:)))

-D

Comment: Have you used a debugger such as byebug or pry and put a breakpoint in there at round 6 to see what's going on?

Comment: I've actually never used a debugger yet. Will def look into those. Thanks Max

Comment: The code is throwing errors when the array passed is `[2,5,1,4,8,6,7,3,100,99, 1]`. It has underneath logic error. I'd suggest you write your code by following the [algorithm's pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) which you can find on wikipedia

Comment: After you learn what the problem is, and correct your code, I suggested you post it at SO's sister site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). There you will get good advice on how to improve it. Your code looks like a direct port from a procedural language like C and does not benefit from any of Ruby's language features. The first tip-off is  your third line, `for i in (0..(num-2))`. Yes, `for` loops are part of the language, but in practice they are *never* used.

Comment: @sam thanks! studied the pseudocode for a bit and couldn't fully understand it. will circle back later.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the feedback. Will work on my accent :))

Comment: Derek, I just had a look at various implementations of the insertion sort algorithm in Ruby. To my surprise they all were very procedural looking and the majority employed a `for` loop. I forgot I had presented a Ruby implementation myself, at [Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254359/insertion-sort-implemented-in-ruby). It contains a single statement yet is quite efficient, leveraging the power of Ruby methods. See also @JörgWMittag's excellent answer to a same question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 6th round error:
6 [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 100, 99]

I found out the error was due to the setting of "count < len", which
excluded the last round. By fixing this, I set "the count <= len".

```
while count <= len
```

The final code is as below and can run smoothly.

```
def insertion_sort(list)
  num = list.length
  for i in (0..(num-2))
    if list[i] > list[i+1] && i == 0
      list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
    elsif list[i] == list[i+1]
      i+=1
    elsif list[i] > list[i+1] && i > 0
      len = (list[0..(i+1)].length)
      list2 = list[0..(i+1)]
      list = list - list2
      count = 0
      while count <= len
        if list2[len-1] < list2[len-2]
           list2[len-2],list2[len-1]= list2[len-1],list2[len-2] 
        elsif  list2[len-1] == list2[len-2]
          count+=1
          len-=1
        else
          count+=1
          len-=1
        end
      end
      list = list2 + list  
    end
  end
  list
end

p insertion_sort([2,1,4,8,6,7,3,100,99])
p insertion_sort([136,4180,53,1,22,17])
p insertion_sort([3980,1,20,5,8,10])
```

YET!
The new question is, if the array contained 2 identical integer,

p insertion_sort([3980,1,20,5,8,8,10])

The error below would occur.
abc.rb:7:in `>': comparison of Integer with nil failed (ArgumentError)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU6dV.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Please ask your 'new' question in its own separate question (put link to this one). Not only does that conform to the standards of this site, you're also far more likely to actually get responses.

Comment: @ouflak thanks for the editing! and appreciate your feedbacks